# unable to authenticate with google bigquery storage api

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract data via Get Data in Excel using SIMBA ODBC Driver and encountered this error whenever I extract large rows of data: **Unable to authenticate with Google BigQuery Storage API. Check your account permissions.**

I put a check on the "**Allow High-Throughput API for Large Result queries**" in the SIMBA ODBC Advanced Options as shown below, but I'm still getting the same error.

[image: error google bigquery storage api]

Any idea what's the right config for this error?

Comment: Check on the GCP side if your key has the right permissions. It looks like you cannot use storage api.

Comment: Hi @Denoma, Are you using a service account for authentication ? If yes, then you need to provide the path to the service account's private key file in the ODBC connection settings.

Comment: Hi @DhirajSingh I'm using user authentication.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.